# Htaccess use https on WWW and non-WWW except other subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I recently bought and integrated HTTPS on my website, on which I use to develop other websites on subdomains. HTTPS is working perfectly on both www and non-www website, as it was registered.

I used following command to automatically redirect to https from all the subpages:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But I have a lots of websites on `something.mydomain.com` and other subdomains, which now automatically redirect to https and of course display error of untrusted connection and security issues because a certificate was not registered to those subdomains.

Can please someone point me to right direction, how should the command look like to redirect all the subdomains to non-https versions except www subdomain? So it would not anymore display errors to clients?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect only www.mydomain.com to HTTPS version, use

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "^www\." [NC]
RewriteCond "%{SERVER_PORT}" "^80$"
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I used your code and re-wrote it as I needed. Solution in another comment.

Answer (score 0):

So the next code does the trick now:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "^www\." [OR]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "^domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond "%{SERVER_PORT}" "^80$"
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

So it redirects `HTTP://www.domain.com` to `HTTPS://www.domain.com` , but excludes other subdomains. It also redirects `HTTP://domain.com` to `HTTPS://domain.com`.